# Develop JavaScript application on Android Studio

Tags: javascript, cordova

How do I develop JavaScript applications using android studio?

I can actually import cordova JavaScript based code into android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Android Studio uses Java- is that what you meant? However, if you did mean JavaScript, you can add this repo.

> https://github.com/manifestinteractive/android-studio-filetypes

From the menu, go to File -> Import Settings. Locate the settings.jar file from the repo. Go to "Select Components to Import", make sure you have "File types" checked, and you're good to go!

Comment: Thank you Zack105 for your prompt response. I did actually mean JavaScript and with this information, I believe I will be fine.